# Cant display Title name in H2 tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery, .net

I have one aspx Page in that i have to Print Title in betwen of all H2 tag i had written code but it cant display the output that i expected....

```
 aspx code
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("h2").each(function (index) {
       this.innerHTML = "Section " + index;
  });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="div1">
  <h2 title="kj"></h2>
  <h2 title="kl"></h2>
  <h2 title="lo"></h2>
  </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have included jQuery anywhere. You need to reference it first. Also it is recommended to use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead of innerHTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("h2").each(function (index) {
            $(this).html("Section " + index);
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="div1">
                <h2 title="kj"></h2>
                <h2 title="kl"></h2>
                <h2 title="lo"></h2>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this after including jquery js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("h2").each(function (index) {
   $(this).innerHTML = "Section " + index;
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could even decide to create the `<h2>` at that point.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div').prepend('<h2>Your text1</h2>');
    $('#div').prepend('<h2>Your text2</h2>');
    $('#div').prepend('<h2>Your text3</h2>');
});
```

You can also add all properties in there such as id, title and class if needed.